# SQL Query not working in VBA. throwing Automation Error

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Can someone look up and tell me whats wrong in the following VB code

```
mssql1 = "select TOP 1 [Test Date]from [AllSamples].[dbo].[Results](select TOP 2[Test Date] from [AllSamples].[dbo].[Results] where ([Sample ID] = '" & Split(Sheet1.Cells(i, 6), "-")(0) & "' And [Sample No.] = '" & Split(Sheet1.Cells(i, 6), "-")(1) & "') Order BY [Test Date] DESC) Order BY [Test Date] ASC"
```

It is taking the tag number and splitting it accordingly into samples id and sample number. 
please correct the query

Comment: Please update your code to show exactly how you're building the SQL.  This is only half there...   If you `Debug.Print` the final SQL does it look as you expect?

Comment: If i write the SQL query it works perfectly fine. But in VB it is throwing error.

Comment: There are two queries there (two selects) with no differentiation (i.e. GO type statements) to separate them. Are you trying to perform some kind of join? union? If you want the top 1 Test Date from the first query and the top 2 Test Date from the second query, try a UNION in between. Also, while it may not be affecting anything, you should put put spaces between things ([Test Date]from) etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL you are missing field list after TOP 1 and then from before the subquery and alias for subquery. It should be something like:

```
mssql1 = "select TOP 1 * from " & _ 
" (select TOP 2 [Test Date] from [AllSamples].[dbo].[Results] " & _
" ... Order BY [Test Date] DESC) tmp Order BY [Test Date] ASC"
```

And, do not forget to use parameters instead of those string concatenations to prevent SQL injection attack and other string problems.

Comment: Automation Error

Comment: @prachi, what do you mean?.

Comment: Throws an Automation Error

Comment: @prachi, I can't see your screen, what error it throws? And also I don't see the full code you are trying (neither your table structures).